# Uniform convergence of $\int _0^\infty \frac {P_1(t)}{z+t} dt $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to show that $\int _0^\infty \frac {P_1(t)}{z+t} dt $ uniformly converges for $z=r e^{i \theta}$ such that $-\pi + \delta \leq \theta \leq \pi - \delta, 0<\delta<\pi$ and $P_1(t)= t-[t]-\frac 1 2$ is the sawtooth function. I am reading the proof of the Stirling formula for gamma functions and this convergence is necessary for the proof. I think instead of $\int _0^\infty \frac {P_1(t)}{z+t} dt$ we could consider $\int _0^\infty \frac {1}{z+t} dt$ since the sawtooth function takes values between $[-1/2, 1/2]$. But then I dont see how this converges since we could take $r$ arbitrarily small. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the integral as an infinite sum by considering each interval $t\in(n,n+1)$ separately. We obtain

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{P_1(t)}{z+t}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{t-(n+1/2)}{z+t}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[1-(n+z+1/2)\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n+z}\right)\right]$$

One can further show that

$$1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln\left(1+x\right)=\mathcal{O}(x^2)~~,~~ x>0$$

and hence the sum converges.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the last part do you consider $ln(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$? In that case I could not obtain $O(x^2)$ since I could not get rid of $x/2$.

Comment: That's not enough, you have to go to the next order in taylor series to see it.

Comment: I see, then $x/2$'s cancels out! thank you again.